# Al imprimir un HTML con Ctrl+p se puede separar el contenido por hojas?

Tags: html, css, pdf

como están? espero que muy bien.

Tengo un reporte en HTML y php actualmente lo estoy imprimiendo con las teclas Ctrl+p y alli me permite imprimirlo o guardarlo en PDF si quiero.

El problema es que me imprime unos valores que deberian estar unidos en diferentes hojas:

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el ejemplo como ven los títulos de la tabla quedan en la hoja de arriba deberían estar pegados con cada foto.

Puedo hacer que con esa opción de Ctrl+p me divida la información por secciones o por hojas?

```
<br>
<center>
<h3><font color="#000">REPORTE</font></h3>
</center>

<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Customer</th>
<td style='background:#ffffff;'><font color="#000000"> <b>USUARIO</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Insp. By</th>
<td style='background:#ffffff;'><font color="#000000"> <b><?php echo $datos['insby'] ; ?> </b></font></td>
</tr>
</table>

<br><br>





<table border='1' style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Group</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Shift</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Fleet</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>First truck</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>First position</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Last truck</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Last position</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Date on</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Date off</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Scrap date</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['grupo_dese']; ?> </b></font></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['turno_dese']; ?> </b></font></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['flota_servde']; ?> </b></font></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['primer_equip']; ?> </b></font></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['primer_pos']; ?> </b></font></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['equipo_servide']; ?> </b></font></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['pos_deservi']; ?> </b></font></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['fecha_primermt']; ?> </b></font></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['fecha_ultides']; ?> </b></font></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['fecha_desech']; ?> </b></font></td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>


<table border='1' style="width: 100%;">
<tr bgcolor='#130430' align='center'>
    <td colspan='8' style='background-color:#1dd551;color:#ffffff;'><strong>Data</strong></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Internal #CDC</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Serial</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Size</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Pattern</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Spec</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>SC</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>Brand</th>
<th style='background:#02082e;'>OTD</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['nro_interservi']; ?></b></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['serial_servtec']; ?></b></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['tamano_servi']; ?></b></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['diseno_servi']; ?></b></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['compuesto_servi']; ?></b></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['sc_servitec']; ?></b></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['marca_servi']; ?></b></td>
<td style='background:#ffffff;text-align:center;'><font color="#000000"> <b> <?php echo $datos['otd_servi']; ?></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar hay dos preguntas en tu articulo:
- 1. ¿Como dividir la información por secciones o por hojas?
- 2. Los títulos de la tabla que quedan en la hoja de arriba deberían estar pegados con cada foto.

Para la primera pregunta deberías probar con los [estilos CSS para impresió](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/)n:

```
@media print {
  body { font-size: 10pt }
  footer {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

Dentro de las propiedades que puedes añadir en los estilos de impresión encontrarás: **page-break** que define cuando romper la información con una rotura de página. Con esta propiedad podrías forzar a pasar a la siguiente página después de cada bloque de información, colocando cada bloque de información en una página:

```
@media print {
  .bloque__informacion {
     page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

Comment: excelente voy a probar y ya te cuento.

Comment: me funciono perfectamente tu respuesta. muchas gracias.